# Retrieving data from database field, terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I'm retrieving data (thirdLink) from my database with the following code:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *viewParamsDogs = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParamsDogs setValue:@"mydogs" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParamsDogs success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {


        //DOG PHOTO


      self.dogData = [responseObject mutableCopy];

        NSDictionary *dic = [responseObject valueForKey: @"field_pet_photo_path"];
                             NSArray *arr = [dic valueForKey: @"und"];
                             NSDictionary *dic2= [arr objectAtIndex : 0];
                             NSString *path = [dic2 valueForKey: @"safe_value"];


    if([path length]>0) {

            NSString *ImageURL = path;
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];

            self.dogimageView.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        } else {

            NSString *ImageURL = @"paw.png";
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
            self.dogimageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
      }

  } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
```

The field is populated and the data is returned, but this line is throwing me the following error:

```
  NSString *thirdLink = responseObject[@"field_pet_photo_path"][@"und"][0][@"safe_value"];
```

> [__NSCFArray objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x149857d40 terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

Does anyone know how I should be writing this line to properly grab the returned data (url) in field_pet_photo_path? **See returned data below:**

```
"field_pet_photo_path" =         {
            und =             (
                                {
                    format = "<null>";
                    "safe_value" = "/files/stored/1460652721.jpg";
                    value = "/files/stored/1460652721.jpg";
                }
            );
        };
```

Comment: One of those dictionaries is, in fact, as array.  Put a breakpoint on the `self.dogData` line and look at it in the debugger.

Comment: @trojanfoe I figured as much - I'm just not sure how to change how that line of code should be written?

Comment: Depends what the data structure actually looks like.

Comment: @trojanfoe Returned data structure pasted above?

Comment: Well that looks correct, so something doesn't add up.

Comment: Can you add the results of logging `[operation responseString]`

Comment: Can you print the data as requested above - it appears you are not getting the data structure you expect so it would be useful to see exactly what is being received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *dic = [responseObject valueForkey : @"field_pet_photo_path];
NSArray *arr = [dic valueForkey : @"und"];
NSDictionary *dic2= [arr objectAtIndex : 0];
NSString *path = [dic2 valueForkey : @"safe_value"];
```

If required key name or key string with double quote then use like, `@"\"safe_value\""`

Hope this will help :)

Update :

Try to replace `NSString *path = [dic2 valueForkey : @"safe_value"];` with

`NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dic2 valueForkey : @"safe_value"]];`

Comment: Tried this (see above code edit), though now I get this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14901bea0' On the line:     if([path length]>0) {

Comment: I also logged path, and I get the result I'm looking for... so not sure why the error happens. eg. This is path (
    "http://myurl.com/files/stored/1460655708.jpg"
)

Comment: So what's the problem? you got result what you want.

Comment: Yes but  for some reason however using the above code and the code I had causes the NSException crash the moment I try and move past that specific code block?

Comment: What you exactly want now? or where error is happening? I am not exactly getting your comment

Comment: See above code edits. When I run the app, it crashes on this line:  if([path length]>0) { and the error is: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1327d4e00'

Comment: Ahhh yes. Thank you! Hahaha. Strange though - everything seems to work, but my imageView is just white instead of displaying the actual photo? Thought maybe it was because I hooked something up wrong but everything seems to be in order? Maybe my image display code is wrong?